# Is it beneficial to replace a simple Python class with a closure?

Tags: python, closures

I have the following Python class:

```
class class A:
    """a class that increments internal variable"""
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x
    def incr(self):
        self._x = (self._x + 1) % 10
        return self._x
```

I heard a talk that recommended that such classes with just a constructor and another method really should just be replaced by a function.

So here is my attempt (for Python 2.7):

```
def incrX(x): 
    """closure that increments internal variable"""
    d = {'x' : x}
    def incr():
        d['x'] = (d['x'] + 1) % 10
        return d['x'] 
    return incr
```

Running it:

```
def test1():
    """testing closure vs. class"""
    print 'class...'
    a = A(10)
    print a.incr()
    print a.incr()

    print 'closure...'
    incr = incrX(10)
    print incr()
    print incr()

$ python closure.py 
running closure experiments
class...
1
2
closure...
1
2
```

So my question is:

Is there a benefit to replacing a class like A with a closure? Just trying to understand closures better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real benefit of closures and higher-order functions is that they can represent what the programmer sometimes has in mind.  If you as the programmer find that what you have in mind is a piece of code, a function, an instruction on how to compute something (or do something), then you should use a closure for this.

If, on the other hand, what you have in mind is more like an object, a thing (which happens to have some properties, methods, instructions, capabilities, etc.), then you should program it as an object, a class.

In your case I think the best way to implement this is neither ;-)  I'd do this with a generator:

```
def incrX(i):
  while True:
    i += 1
    i %= 10
    yield i

incr = incrX(10)
print incr.next()
print incr.next()
```

Comment: Thanks @Alfe, the class was a simplification of a Camera class I had that generates viewpoints - not sure if I can apply the generator idea. I guess there's no clear cut reason to always replace a class with just these type of 2 methods with a function.

Comment: @M-V : Laotseu said : "closures are poor-men's objects, and objects are poor-men's closures" ;) More seriously: while having some decent support for functional programming, Pytho, is still first and foremost an OO language, and closures are implemented as objects. It's a nice to have feature when that's all you really need (most decorator functions etc), but there's nothing wrong with a class acting as a closure - in fact you can even implement the magic `__call__` method to really mimic a closure when it makes sense (which would be the case in your drilled-down example).

Comment: @M-V: You can of course have a method of your camera be this generator.  But that would probably be wrong here, I think.  Most likely the next number to be delivered by your camera should be stored in a field of that object, just as you implemented in your question.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - thanks. Yes, that Lao Tseu, the uber Lisper. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With a closure, one can save the `self` variable. In particular, when there are many variables to be passed, a closure could be more readable.

```
class Incr:
    """a class that increments internal variable"""
    def __init__(self, i):
        self._i = i
    def __call__(self):
        self._i = (self._i + 1) % 10
        return self._i
```

```
def incr(i): 
    """closure that increments internal variable"""
    def incr():
        nonlocal i
        i = (i + 1) % 10
        return i
    return incr
```

```
print('class...')
a = Incr(10)
print(a())   # 1
print(a())   # 2

print('closure...')
b = incr(10)
print(b())   # 1
print(b())   # 2
```

Answer (score 0):

closure binds data to functions in a weird way. on the other side, data classes try to separate data from functions. To me both of them are bad design. Never use them. OO(class) is a much more convient and natural way.